# Visual studio heap profiling not working anymore

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I used Visual Studio profiling on vs2015, and for a few times it worked great, I could see  all allocations, call stack, etc. After a couple of days it stopped working, I could take snapshots but when clicking on one of the entries it only showed "Analyzing heap details..." at the bottom but nothing appeared. I  installed vs2017 to check and the same happened! It  worked for a few days but now it's stuck again. There must be something wrong that I'm doing, but I don't have any ideas what  it could be, anyone had the same issue, and discovered the reasons for this and how to solve it? Thanks!

PS: I'm on the same project when using vs2017, and the compiler is still 2015, I cannot change that at the moment.

Comment: post screenshot

Comment: Screenshot of what? There is nothing to see, in the list of snapshots I get the  allocations  numbers and the memory increase, but  when I click on one of those I only see a message at the bottom but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

​Cool, disabling and re-enabling the heap profiler solves this.